# Android VPN (ikEv2) Client

Tags: android, vpn, android-vpn-service

I am trying to create android client for VPN using IKEv2 protocol, but on this topic there is almost no help to get started. Our backend team have provided me remote_server_url, username and password. I was able to create iOS client successfully with these credentials.

I'd appreciate if anyone can point me in right direction.

Comment: Hi Asad, have you found a sample project for IKEv2 in Android? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.strongswan.android) on play store that connects vpn using ikev2 protocol. This is the their github [repo](https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan). You will get help from this repo.

Comment: HI Sadda, I have the exact same issue. Can't find any documentation how to make an IKEv2 client in Kotlin. The repo you posted above, seems to be the StrongSwan server side code, no? I can't see any Java or Kotlin client code. May you clarify please? Thanks

Comment: Hi Houman, Please follow this link. https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/tree/master/src/frontends/android Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much.